# HTML 5 localStorage not working

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a simple application written in Visual Studio 2010.

The java script behind a button click:

```
function btnClicked() {
    alert(localStorage["name"]);
    localStorage["name"] = "Bill";
}
```

When I click it the first time, I get "undefined" and the second time I get "Bill", which is correct.

But if I restart the application, I'd hope it would display "Bill" the first time I click the button.

It doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: Is this running in a web browser like Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari, etc?

Comment: provide more code where `localStorage` is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I restart the application...

... you restart it. Which includes wiping any `localStorage` contents. Try running your page in a browser and it should work just fine.

Comment: This works now. But it sure makes it difficult to debug.